# $\dim(\mbox{im}(f)) = \dim(U)$ and $\dim(\ker(g)) = \dim(V)-\dim(U)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U, V, W$ be vector-spaces over the same field $K$ with linear transformations $$f:U\to V , g:V\to W $$ so that $$g\circ f$$ is an Isomorphism.
Show that $$\dim(\mbox{im}(f)) = \dim(U)$$ and $$\dim(\ker(g)) = \dim(V)-\dim(U)$$$$$$My idea is to say that because of the Isomorphism between the linear transformations the vector spaces equal each other because of the bijection. Is this sufficient enough (or even right)?

Comment: No, the spaces need not be equal. Since $g\circ f$ you can say that $\dim U=\dim W$, though. Do you know the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: @egreg Our professor just wrote it on the board but it was not proven and I have not really seen it in applied yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: since $g\circ f$ is an isomorphism, you can prove that $f$ is injective and that $g$ is surjective. Apply rank-nullity.

Why is $f$ injective? Suppose $f(u_1)=f(u_2)$; then $g(f(u_1))=g(f(u_2))$ or $g\circ f(u_1)=g\circ f(u_2)$. By hypothesis $g\circ f$ is injective, so …

Why is $g$ surjective? Suppose $w\in W$; then, since $g\circ f$ is surjective by hypothesis, $w=g\circ f(u)$ for some $u\in U$. Can you find $v\in V$ such that $w=g(v)$?

Comment: ok I knew how to solve it if I could prove that $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective, but I do not know how to show that

Comment: since f is proven injective, $v\in V$, $v = f(u)$ is $w=g(v)$ isnt it?

Comment: @sj134 Yes, $v=f(u)$.

Comment: alright then thanks for your help